# spring: multiple parameters in one POST

Tags: spring, forms, post, spring-mvc

Hi I am using Spring MVC 3 with annotations.

How do I use multiple `ModelAttributes` in one *Spring* `<form:form>` **tag**?

It all works perfectly to use one ModelAttribute, but nesting them and using two doesn't work. Is there a way to do this? Or how would I send a **ModelAttribute** *and a* **RequestParameter** in the same **POST** request?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with nested objects?

Comment: @axtavt:well I'm unsure how to nest them. If I make a "super" form that nests the two forms I'm actually using it says the modelattributes are null. In some other cases the button doesn't do anything at all. Could you give an examp^le on how to nest them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily combine several objects into one model attribute using a holder object, like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    ...
}

public class Bar {
    private String name;
    ...
}

public class FooBarForm {
    private Foo foo;
    private Bar bar;
    ...
}
```

.

```
<form:form modelAttriubte = "fooBarForm" method = "post">
    <form:input path = "foo.name" />
    <form:input path = "bar.name" />
</form:form>
```

.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute FooBarForm form, ...) { ... }
```

`@RequestParam` can be combined with `@ModelAttribute` as well (note that Spring tags don't support `@RequestParam`):

```
<form:form modelAttriubte = "foo" method = "post">
    <form:input path = "name" />
    <input type = "text" name = "bar_name" />
</form:form>
```

.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute Foo foo, 
    @RequestParam("bar_name") String barName) { ... }
```